# Why can't humans digest dietary fiber when we can digest starch?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, enzymes, digestive-system, digestion

So, I can see that there's a couple of questions touching on this subject already, but none of them answer the aspect that I'm curious about:

Dietary fiber is a polymer composed of multiple starch molecules chained together, and starch molecules are polymers composed of multiple sugar molecules chained together, right?

So, why are our bodies are able to digest starches and not dietary fiber, when the process for digesting starches involves breaking up the starch polymers into sugar molecules? Why can't the same enzymes used to break down starches break dietary fiber down into its component starch molecules, or break individual sugar molecules off of the ends of them?

Is it simply a matter of time, and we simply pass put the partially-digested remains of the dietary fiber because it doesn't remain in our gut long enough to properly digest? I know that cows have multiple stomachs to facilitate the digestion of grass, but I also know that they've got symbiotic bacteria helping them out as well.

Comment: You are mistaken about [dietary fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietary_fiber) — please read the linked wikipedia page and [edit] or delete your post according to whether you still have a question.

Comment: @tyersome Huh, it looks like there's more than one kind of dietary fiber. TIL. I think I'm asking about cellulose specifically, then.

Comment: Then I suggest you read up on what cellulose is — it is not starch (the bonds between glucose units are different).

Comment: @tyersome If the correct answer is something like "starches are held together with A bonds, dietary fibers are held together with B bonds, and the enzymes only work to break A bonds for X reason", I'd be happy to accept that answer.

Comment: How much organic chemistry do you know? This is ultimately a question about glycosidic bonds ... and since dietary fiber isn't one thing so there is no general answer, which means you need to focus your question.

Comment: @tyersome "How much organic chemistry do you know?" I've watched some cooking videos on Youtube by people like Ann Reardon and Adam Ragusea, and I know the general sort of high-school stuff about cells.

Comment: Did the nice answer from @MattDMo help you? If so please accept it — if not, please leave a comment explaining why. In addition, your post needs to be edited to fit this answer. ——— I suspect you will need to learn the basics of organic chemistry to really appreciate his answer. If so, there are many resources available online, but I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry) can be very helpful.

Comment: @tyersome I was waiting 24 hours so that people in other time zones could post their answers, then I forgot. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "starches are held together with A bonds, dietary fibers are held together with B bonds, and the enzymes only work to break A bonds for X reason"

What you wrote [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/105144/why-cant-humans-digest-dietary-fiber-when-we-can-digest-starch#comment191010_105144) is correct. `A` is primarily an α(1,4)-[glycosidic bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycosidic_bond) and `B` in [cellulose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose) is primarily a β(1,4)-glycosidic bond.

[image: alpha vs. beta glucosidic bonds, comparing maltose and cellobiose]

<sup>*From [Chemistry of Life](https://www.abpischools.org.uk/topic/chemistryoflife/5) at abpischools.org.uk*</sup>

[Maltose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltose) is one of the [disaccharides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaccharide) produced when starches are broken down, while [cellobiose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellobiose) is a disaccharide from cellulose.

Alpha bonds are broken during digestion of starches by the [enzyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme) known as [α-amylase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-amylase), in particular one that specializes in breaking α-(1,4) bonds (there are other alpha bonds, like α-(1,2), as well). Humans express a number of α-amylases. However, [β-(1,4)-amylase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-amylase) is only expressed in bacteria, fungi, and plants. Even cows and other grass-eating animals can't digest cellulose on their own – they have massive colonies of bacteria in their digestive systems to do it for them.

The reason α-amylases can't break β bonds is that the two different molecules have rather different chemical "shapes", even though the structures look very similar in the flat drawing above. You may have heard that enzymes work by a sort of "lock and key" model. The substrate (the thing being chemically altered by the enzyme) fits into a specifically-shaped binding pocket surrounding the active site on the enzyme, just like a key fitting into a lock. If the key is the wrong shape, sometimes even by just a little bit, it won't fit properly and won't open the lock. In the same way, if a potential substrate doesn't have the correct chemical "shape", it won't fit into the binding pocket of the enzyme and be acted upon.